# Are cutscenes skippable on console versions of Mass Effect 3?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I'm annoyed at being forced to watch the entire length of cutscenes play out. Is there a way to skip past sections of dialog, or skip the entire cutscene altogether? I'm playing on Xbox 360, but I assume the potential solution is the same for PS3 and possibly PC.

*(I realize that this isn't the sort of game that you'd normally want to skip past the story elements in, and typically I wouldn't be, but I had to replay certain sections of the game and did not want to sit through the same story progression a second time.)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't noticed any way to skip the "major" cutscenes in this game on the Xbox 360.

However, you can skip dialog by pressing "X."  The person delivering the line will immediately stop, and the game skips ahead to either the next line or waits for your input if you've got a dialog choice to make.

I believe this would be "Square" on the PS3 and "Space" on the PC, but I don't have those versions and can't confirm.

Comment: This is the same on PC, only some cutscenes can be skipped.

Comment: Yeah, it's Square on PS3. "Major" scenes like the opening are totally unskippable.

Comment: Thanks guys for helping me confirm the keys :)  I couldn't find it in the online manuals.

Comment: Thanks. I was assuming all cutscenes were unskippable because the first few weren't, and I was pressing 'A' instead of 'X'.

Answer (score 2):

Any cut-scenes that are "skippable" can be passed by pressing X (Xbox360). However, the majority of these scenes are considered important and thus, skipping them is impossible. You can also skip dialogue by pressing X on the Xbox controller.